# Does my SNMP device just not support snmpbulkget?

Tags: snmp, net-snmp, snmpv3

I've got a [Cyberpower 81002 PDU](https://www.cyberpowersystems.com/product/pdu/pdu81002/). It works well. In trying to get data from it using snmpget for multiple OIDs I would sometimes get:

```
Error in packet
Reason: (tooBig) Response message would have been too large.
```

So I learned about snmpbulkget. The device supports SNMPv3, so I thought this would be a good option. But I can't get even a simple snmpbulkget for a single OID to work, even when specifying only non-repeaters and no repetitions. That is, I have the following results:

```
> snmpget -v 3 10.103.129.1 -u user CPS-MIB::ePDU2DeviceStatusLoad.1
CPS-MIB::ePDU2DeviceStatusLoad.1 = Gauge32: 17
>snmpbulkget -v 3 10.103.129.1 -u user CPS-MIB::ePDU2DeviceStatusLoad.1
Timeout: No Response from 10.103.129.1
>snmpbulkget -v 3 -Cn1 -Cr0 10.103.129.1 -u user CPS-MIB::ePDU2DeviceStatusLoad.1
Timeout: No Response from 10.103.129.1
```

Am I missing something obvious in trying to use snmpbulkget? Or does this device just not fully support SNMPv3?

Comment: It is the device who decides when to return "tooBig", and when not to respond, https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3416 So consult the vendor.

Comment: My question is not about that though. I'm trying to use snmpbulkget to since snmpget gives the tooBig response. But even for a single OID, snmpbulkget does not work.

Comment: The troubleshooting is exactly the same. If the agent gives you an error response or no response at all, the problem is not on your client/manager side.